# Add one property to json in python

Tags: python, json

I have the below json, I want to add one more property:

```
[   {
        "A": 1,
        "B": "str"
    },
    {
        "A": 2,
        "B": "str2"
    },
    {
        "A": 3,
        "B": "str3"
    }
]
```

So I want something like this:

```
[   {
        "A": 1,
        "B": "str",
        "C": "X"
    },
    {
        "A": 2,
        "B": "str2",
        "C": "X"
    },
    {
        "A": 3,
        "B": "str3",
        "C": "X"
    }
]
```

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: 1.  Add the exact same key/val on each occasion, or different ones?   2.  Modify existing dicts, or create new ones?  3. Do you have json (as written) or a dict (as shown)?

Comment: Is it a json STRING or a json OBJECT (aka, dictionary)?

Answer (score 5):

Loop through each dict obj in the list and add `required key value pair that you want`:

**List Before**

```
list1 = [       
   {
        "A": 1,
        "B": "str"
    },
    {
        "A": 2,
        "B": "str2"
    },
    {
        "A": 3,
        "B": "str3"
    }
]
```

**The code**

```
for l in list1:
    l['C'] = 'X'

print(list1)
```

**List After i.e Output**

```
[{'A': 1, 'B': 'str', 'C': 'X'}, {'A': 2, 'B': 'str2', 'C': 'X'}, {'A': 3, 'B': 'str3', 'C': 'X'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> j = [ { "A": 1, "B": "str" }, { "A": 2, "B": "str2" }, { "A": 3, "B": "str3" } ]
>>> [i.update({'C': 'X'}) for i in j]
>>> j
[{'A': 1, 'B': 'str', 'C': 'X'}, {'A': 2, 'B': 'str2', 'C': 'X'}, {'A': 3, 'B': 'str3', 'C': 'X'}]
```

Or, as per coldspeed's comment:

```
>>> for item in j:
...     item['C'] = 'X'  
... 
>>> j
[{'A': 1, 'B': 'str', 'C': 'X'}, {'A': 2, 'B': 'str2', 'C': 'X'}, {'A': 3, 'B': 'str3', 'C': 'X'}]
```

Comment: Any chance you can explain what you did here?

Comment: I'd advise against using list comprehensions to generate side effects. You're on the right track, but use a loop instead.

Comment: (responding to your edit) an assignment to `i` will end up modifying `j` (print it out and see), because the `for` loop iterates over the references. In short, the `new_list` is not required. (also, I did not downvote)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. No worries.